# How to download image using webClient

Tags: java, webclient

I am retrieving data from external API and saving it to MongoDb. However images that I am retrieving are not saving in DB. Here how my request look like:

```
url: "https//:myURL.com"
{
  "command": "getClients"
}
```

Here how the response looks like:

```
{
    "available": true,
    "data": [
        {
       
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Some description",
        "date": "date",
"image1": "imageURL",
    "image2": "imageURL"

    },
    {
     
        "id": "2",
        "name": "SomeName",
        "date": "date",
"image1": "imageURL",
"image2": "imageURL"

    }
]
```

}

```
The response class:

public class ClientList {

    
    private Boolean available;
    private List<Clients> data;

}


@Document(collection = "clients")
public class Clients {

@Id
private Long id;
private String name;
private Timestamp date;
private String image1;
private String image2;

//getters and setters
}
```

Here what I have done:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        RequestDto requestBody = RequestDto("getClients");

    client.post()
        .uri(new URI("https//:myURL.com"))
        .header("token", "myToken") //I have a header as well
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bodyValue(requestBody)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(ClientList.class)
        .block();
}
```

}

Further I have ReactiveMongoRepository for saving. But I dont think the problem in him.

```
List<ClientDto> clientList = wrapper.getData()
                            .stream()
                            .map(product -> fill(client, id))
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    clientRepository.saveAll(clientList )
                            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("Log", clientList .size(), client))
                            .subscribe()
```

Comment: Do you want to save the url or the image file?

Comment: Yes! I dont want to dowload image, just save the link

Comment: Can you share the code block you save the link?

Comment: Edited, have a look please

Comment: Are you doing this in a spring context?

Comment: Yes, as well as just in java

Comment: Are any records thrown into your mongo? Or is it just the image fields left blank?

Comment: Everything is recorded except image. The fields itself (image1, image2 ) are not there as well

Comment: Can you add an image of your `clientList` object that you call `saveAll` method?

Comment: I dont know what are you about, I think its there already. Class Clients